# How to know if a question is good for MATHSE or MathOverflow or Others?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, mathoverflow, se-sites

Often a question asked where, no one answer or comment on it. Sometimes I think may be it's better to ask the question for other sites, like MathOverflow. But it is considered non-ethical to ask a single question on multiple sites.

How to know what questions are better to be asked here or on other sites like MathOverflow?

Comment: If you want to be safe: ask it here first, and if you still don't have responses in a week or two and it does seem sufficiently advanced, flag the question for MO migration.

Comment: Re: *But it is considered non-ethical to ask a single question on multiple sites.* Actually, it seems that MO and MSE are more lenient to cross posting than SE network in general. However, you should follow too basic rules: 1) Do not post on both sites simultaneously, leave some time to see what response you get on the site where you poste first. 2) Always include links to the question on another site in both copies. You can find a bit more in the links available [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) and in other posts on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: "leave some time to see what response you get on the site where you post first." Where "some time" means several days, not several minutes.

Comment: Thank you everyone. How to flag the question for MO migration?